# Moving an element on the HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have drawn a rectangle on the canvas and I just want it to move every half a second. I'm trying to increase the y coordinate every 0.5 seconds -- but nothing is happening.

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VegWR/)

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas); 

setInterval(function(){
var x = 100;
var y= 300;
var block = ctx.fillRect(x, y, 100, 120);
y++;


},500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting your x and y for each call so they never increase. Also, you need to clear previous drawn rectangle or they will becomes smeared.

To be able to cancel the loop later you can consider storing the timer id returned from `setInterval` so you can call `clearInterval(id)` when needed (ie. at a condition).

```
var x = 100;
var y = 300;
var tid;

tid = setInterval(function(){
    ctx.clearRect(x - 2, y - 2, 104, 124); /// compensate for anti-aliasing
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 100, 120);
    y++;
},500);
```

A condition could be:

```
if (y > canvas.height) clearInterval(tid);
```

Comment: +1 because I forgot about `clearRect` in my answer :P

Comment: @tmyie clearRect is to clear what is already drawn. When your rectangle moves the old pixels will still be there if you don't clear the area it was drawn into. Due to anti-aliasing you can increase the clearRect a bit (updated). Also be aware of that the loop as it is now will go on forever. Just store the timer id from the setTimeout so you can cancel it later.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain or link to a source explaining why I would have to compensate for anti-aliasing?

Comment: @tmyie it's well known anti-aliasing adds pixels. A monitor can only show whole pixels. When a pixel is "half" one or two (depending on position) are drawn with a different color to give the illusion of being reduced. Since you now have two pixels (at some positions) representing a "half" you need to deal with the extra one put there for this purpose. Anti-aliasing is widely covered on the net.

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
var x = 100;
var y = 300;
```

Out of the function within `setInterval`, so that they don't get reset every frame.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting x and y always to the default values when the function gets executed. You should outsource them.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);


var x = 100;
var y = 300;
setInterval(function(){    
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(x, y, 100, 120, Math.PI * 2, false);
    c.fill();
    x += 10;


},500);
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VegWR/2/) fiddle.